# Openlayers, Geometry.Polygon unexpected identifier in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, openlayers

I have some code displaying polygons on a Openstreetmap with Openlayers. It works well in Firefox but does not work in Chrome or Safari.

The line of code Chrome is complaining about is:

```
var poly = new OpenLayers.​Geometry.​Polygon([polyCoords]);
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

I have included openlayers.js and there are other OpenLayers.Geometry code which Chrome is not complaining about.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Could you print out value of polyCoords variable when you get the error?

Comment: Yes, here are the console.log of the array in Google Chrome. I dont believe it is an error with the data though.
[
Array[2]
0: "59.334524116709"
1: "17.997951304289"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[2]
0: "59.331963137511"
1: "17.997994219634"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[2]
0: "59.331963137511"
1: "17.998037134977"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
]

Comment: But the value of polyCoords is not what is causing this, if i just type: var poly = new OpenLayers.​Geometry.​Polygon(); I still get the same error.